# Rewrite URL in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, url, url-rewriting

I am looking for a rewrite URL tag for such conversion

```
www.example.com/subject.aspx?subject=aa&page=1
```

to

```
www.example.com/subjects/aa/1
```

I tried to add 2 dollars but it showed error in visual studio and it does not let me compile the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<rewrite url="^~/subjects/([A-Za-z]+)/([0-9]+)$" to="~/subject.aspx?subject=$1&amp;page=$2"/>
```

Comment: I am looking out for something like <rewrite url="~/subjects/(.+)/([0-9]+)" to="~/subject.aspx?ebook-subject=$1&amp;page=$2"/>

Comment: Ooops sorry I wrote reverse what you wanted ;-)

Comment: Okay I reversed my answer :-)

Comment: Hello, I also had a typo in my question, Please see the update in bold and update your answer.Thanks

Comment: Oh sure, I see now, updated :-) PS. That's why I "love" regexes, they are so "clear" ;-)

Comment: should there be ~ in place of ^? ALSO, should there be $1 and $2 in Url attribute's value ?

Comment: ^ means beginning of string in regex. This is regular expression. This is good site to learn it: http://www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: Yes in 'to' attribute, $1 and $2 will be replaced with for example aa and 1.

Comment: i tried it bro and it did not work :( It says "The resource cannot be found" for "/subjects/Networks/1". I had similar url redirection but they were sort of different ex :      <rewrite url="~/books/(.+).aspx" to="~/book.aspx?ebook-name=$1"/>

Comment: Your website root directory is not "/" so I added ~.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you're using "/" in your rewrite rule so it creates "virtual directories", one way to bypass this is by using html tag base href.